# XSLT: For each 2 Conditions with XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My problem: both conditions have to be true and it has to run 2 checks on the SAME node(i select a bunch of nodes via //)

currently i leave the node in the for each by using a new //books/authors, but if i take this out(example how i imagine it below the code) it gives me an error.
Any help?

```
   <xsl:for-each select="//node">
    <routes>
      <xsl:variable name="origin" select="@origin"/>
      <xsl:variable name="dest" select="@dest"/>
      Origin: <xsl:value-of select="$origin"/>
      Dest: <xsl:value-of select="$dest"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="//books/authors [substring-before(../../@name, '.') = $origin] | //books/authors [substring-before(../../@name, '.') = $dest] ">
      </xsl:for-each>
```

how i imagine it, so it runs on the same node, but it ouptuts an error

```
      <xsl:for-each select="//books/authors [substring-before(../../@name, '.') = $origin] | //books/authors [substring-before(../../@name, '.') = $dest] ">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax you are looking for is this..

```
<xsl:for-each select="//books/authors[substring-before(../../@name, '.') = $origin and substring-before(../../@name, '.') = $dest] ">
    ....
</xsl:for-each>
```

This would also work...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//books/authors[substring-before(../../@name, '.') = $origin][substring-before(../../@name, '.') = $dest] ">
    ....
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that `../../` gets the "grand-parent" of the `authors` node, so you could also re-write the condition as this... (Although you could probably replace the generic `*` with the actual element name

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[substring-before(@name, '.') = $origin and substring-before(@name, '.') = $dest]/books/authors">

</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: i think this worked. Now i don't have an output at all anymore, but i think thats due to another fault, at least the code gets accepted as proper code! thanks